# iOS Swift - How to add two different colors in a UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

I have two problems regarding the label.

In the first scenario, as I wanted to add two different colors to the label, I did this:

```
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
```

in **viewDidLoad**

```
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: string1,
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(
                name: "Montserrat-Light",
                size: 12.0)!])



        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            value: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            range: NSRange(
                location:0,
                length:25))

        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            value: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            range: NSRange(
                location:42,
                length:3))


        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            value: (UIColor( red: CGFloat(TOSLabelColor[0]), green: CGFloat(TOSLabelColor[1]), blue:CGFloat(TOSLabelColor[2]), alpha: 1.0 )).CGColor
            ,
            range: NSRange(
                location:25,
                length:16))


        bottomLabel.attributedText = myMutableString
```

This code works fine on mobile running iOS 9 or greater but it doesn't work on iOS 8.4. The app crashes in iOS 8.4.

Also, this code is only suitable for static text/label. The second problem is on some other screen I have a table view in which I have a text like this:

> From "America" to "Australia"

I want to display countries in a color and "From" and "to" in a different color. I added on the screen only one label. How can I do that? This is dynamic and I can't implement the previous code.

Comment: You shall need to provide some crash information to help us diagnose your problem: what exactly does Xcode tell you went wrong on iOS 8.4?

Comment: Perhaps it could be a bug in iOS 8.4. Maybe it was fixed in iOS 9.